# Memory Configuration for 32-bit, 64-bit and PAE enabled OS

Tags: memory, memory-management, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I am confuse about memory configuration, i have below questions.

1. if 32-bit os maximum virtual address is 4GB, When i have 4 gb of ram for 32-bit os, What about the virtual memory size ? is it required virtual memory or we can directly use physical memory ?
2. In 32-bit os 12 bits are offset because page size=4k i.e 2^12 and 2^20 for page addresses
   What about 64-bit os, What is offset size ? What is page size ? How it calculated.
3. What is PAE? If enabled how to decide size of PAE, what is maximum and minimum size of extended memory.

Comment: **Single** question per question post, please. "If 32-bit os maximum virtual address is 4GB, When i have 4 gb of ram for 32-bit os, What about the virtual memory size?" - Well, you say it by yourself: maximum size of virtual memory is 4GB. And *virtual memory* is NOT a *disk space*.

Comment: 3. It is a technology to address up to 64G of virtual address space on 32-bit CPUs. Google for it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev if virtual memory is not disk space, lets say i have 2gb of ram and 4gb of virtual memory, where/to ram swap out/in the pages. ? Definition of vitual memory:- Virtual Memory is a storage allocation scheme in which secondary memory can be addressed as though it were part of main memory.

Comment: Swap is a special file which is stored on the hard disk.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, did you mean without swap there is no virtual memory.

Comment: No, I don't mean that virtual memory doesn't exist without swap. I don't understand  your questions. *Virtual memory* is a **scheme** for address *physical memory* (RAM). So by itself, virtual memory doesn't require swap. Swap is required only when *usage* of virtual memory exceeds RAM size.

Comment: @Tsyvarev but your statement above "virtual memory is not disk space" i didnt get it ?

Comment: In you question post you have "virtual memory(disk space)". I have noted that these terms are not the same.

Comment: @Tsyvarev lets say i have 2 gb of RAM, on 32-bit OS, Virtual memory is 4gb. where 2gb is stored ? Secondary Storage ?

Comment: If you **use** 4GB of virtual memory, then part of them may be located in RAM, and other part - in the swap. Sizes of parts could be any, but in sum they should give the total usage of virtual memory. Note, that it is possible to use more than 4GB of virtual memory even on 32-bit OS. But that usage should be from several processes, not from the single one.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, Thanks i will post answer of all my questions soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q.1
Ans:-**

The 32-bit processor includes a 32-bit register, which can store 2^32 and the 64-bit processor includes a 64-bit register, which can store 2^64. 
A 64-bit register can theoretically 16 exabytes of memory.

For 32-bit os maximum virtual memory is 4GB, it can address only up to 4GB of physical RAM (Without PAE).

For the Linux kernel, it works on virtual memory management i.e CPU address, There are many types of addresses For example. bus address, physical address(There are other concepts to access physical memory eg. DMA and IOMMU)

The virtual memory size is the maximum virtual size of a single process.

For more details of 32-bit and 64-bit processor use [link](https://techterms.com/help/difference_between_32-bit_and_64-bit_systems).

**Q.2
Ans:-**

For 64-bit OS address space is 16 exabyte RAM. and generally page size is 8K i.e 2^13 (apart from that there is the concept of hugepages and hugetlb).

64-bit currently uses 48-bit physical addresses that allow you to address up to 256 TBytes of main memory. because the page table is also a page itself and consists of page table entries. Since the number of entries in one table is limited and depends on the entry size and page size, so tables are arranged in multiple levels. There are usually 2 or 3 levels, and sometimes even 4 levels.

General calculation of 64-bit os:-

```
 Number of entries in page table = virtual address space size/page size

                            = 2^(64-13) (if page size is 8K)

                            = 2^51 for maximum page table entries (if you are using whole 64 bits)

Page Size == Frame Size.
```

**Q.3
Ans:-**

For PAE, the page table entry expands from 32 to 36 bits. This allows more space for the physical page address, or page frame number(PFN) field, in the page table entry. In the initial implementations of PAE, the page frame number(PFN) field was expanded from 20 to 24 bits. The size of the "byte offset" from the address being translated is still 12 bits, so total physical address size increases from 32 bits to 36 bits (from 20+12 to 24+12). This increased the physical memory that is theoretically addressable by the CPU from 4 GB to 64 GB.

```
Maximum size of PAE is = 64GB (2^36).
```

For PAE in details use [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension)